# Dell Keyboard Mouse Bluetooth USB Dongle Lost

Tags: usb, bluetooth, wireless-mouse, dell-optiplex, wireless-keyboard

I have lost the Bluetooth USB dongle of Dell's wireless keyboard and mouse (it was a combined set so there was one common dongle).

Is there at all a way to use them? I saw that logitech gives a universal dongle which works on variety of their models. Is there a way to make Dell's work in any way?

Comment: Why don't you buy a new one from Dell - then you'll know it will work.

Comment: Does the mouse or keyboard require a specific dongle? Generally, Bluetooth is Bluetooth.

Comment: Is it really a Bluetooth dongle or a 2.4Ghz wireless dongle? If it's a Bluetooth one, any Bluetooth compatible dongle will work; if not better buy a new one from Dell

Comment: @CaldeiraG Yeah it maybe the wireless dongle. If it is, is the keyboard and mouse useless?

Comment: Pretty much, you would need a new one and because it's a combo dongle it's more difficult to find